# No result after wpdb->insert

Tags: plugins, php, wpdb

I have implemented my own plugin (PHP file). It contains a form with questions with `input type = radio`. I want to submit the answers and load them into the database. My action is calling another PHP file (which gets found properly). However, the browser cannot load anything. After hours of research I found out that my wpdb query stops the procedure, but what am I doing wrong?

```
<?php

//Collecting info
$name = $_POST['name'];
$movie = $_POST['movie'];

//Check if we have all input fields (function does not need check)
if(empty($name)){
    die("Please Choose A Name! <a href='javascript:history.back()'>Back</a><br>");
}
if(empty($movie)){
    die("Please Choose your favourite Movie! <a href='javascript:history.back()'>Back</a><br>");
}

//Load answers to database
global $wpdb;
$table = $wpdb->prefix . 'themovies';
$wpdb->insert($table, array('Name' => $name, 'Movie' => $movie), array('%s', '%s'));

if($insert == true){
    header("location: thankyou.php");
    exit;
}
else
{
    echo "Error";
}
?>
```

Comment: How are you using this PHP file? Are you submitting a form directly to it? The file isn't loading WordPress so no WordPress functions or variables are going to work.

Comment: Hi @JacobPeattie thanks for your answer. I have the following form action: 

<form action="/wp-content/plugins/Movies/register_in_db.php" method="post" id="movies" accept-charset='UTF-8'>

How do I load Wordpress into the file?

Comment: You probably shouldn't. See here for a good overview of a better way to handle forms in WordPress: https://www.sitepoint.com/handling-post-requests-the-wordpress-way/